# What section heading for a CV, regrouping things you do for the community?

Tags: word-choice, heading

In a university researcher's curriculum vitæ, it is typical to split items between categories such as *Education*, *Research activity*, *Publications*, *Teaching*, etc. I want to include as a separate categories the things that you do for the community, in my own group and at large (i.e., people from my research domain). This includes things like peer review of publications and funding proposals, organizing seminars and workshops, etc. *(**Edit**: it is part of my job, not volunteer work outside of the scope of my job.)*

The term I came up with for the name of that category was “Collective responsibilities”, but I am not satisfied at all with that. What name would you suggest in this context?

Comment: I also came up with “Community involvement”, but it does not sound good to me either. And “community service”, while it fits the bill literaly, will not be an acceptable answer!

Comment: What do other researchers' CVs (your colleagues') have? I definitely recall seeing "community service" in university researchers' CVs (and they were native English speakers too); I'm not sure why you're so sure it's unacceptable. Yes, sometimes, "community service" is forced/involuntary, but surely this ought not to be the only connotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Other Professional Activities* or Other *Professional Responsibilities* would suffice, IMHO.

A reasonably granular taxonomy is useful, but only up to a point - at which time, it is useful to have a catch-all category.

EDIT: How about *Professional Community Activities/Responsibilities*? Say it how it is... you need the *professional* to clarify it is work-related, the * Community* to indicate the nature of the work, and optionally - *Activities* or *Responsibilities* - if the title is too long, you could arguably trim this last word without compromising the meaning.

Alternatively, if you don't feel the need to stress *Professional*, *Community Activity* might suffice.

Comment: Yeah, but I already have a catch-all later, and there is just too much in this, which is why I want to segregate this stuff out. (It's for a long-style CV, so 3–4 pages, not a one-page thing.)

Answer (score 1):

If it's something that you do in your own free time that you don't get paid for, then **Volunteer Work** carries none of the negative connotations of Community Service whilst essentially meaning the same thing.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, so I edited the question. +1 though, as it was a valid hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Are these

*Community Collaborations* or *Collaborative Activities*

I might be on the wrong track here, since you might be doing these independently.